# snapd is unavailable in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, snap, ubuntu-core

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. But I think the **snapd** is broken in my system.

When I run `$ snap --version`, I get this response:

```
snap    2.29.4.2~14.04
snapd   unavailable
series  -
```

I have also problem running `$ sudo apt upgrade` and `$ sudo apt -f install`. Every time I get errors such as:

```
Setting up snapd (2.29.4.2~14.04) ...
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
```

Any help?

**Updates below.**

---

Also `lsb_release -a` reports

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

With `dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image | grep -v deinstall`, I get

```
linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic
```

If I run `sudo apt -f install` and `sudo apt upgrade` I get:

```
## To be filed by Masroor ##
```

Comment: Is this a real genuine install of 16.04? I'm guessing it's a server, VPS or other appliance provided by a 3rd party, and has been modified somehow. What's the origin of the install? What does `lsb_release -a` report?

Comment: When I run `lsb_release -a`, I get this:  
No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

Comment: @popey    my  `/snap` directory is empty!!!   What's the problem?    Also `lsb_release -a` reports: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

Comment: Again, what's the origin of this machine? Is it a server / vps?

Comment: @popey   No it is not a server.    When I run `dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image | grep -v deinstall`, I get **linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic**.

Comment: What's the origin of the machine? Was it clean installed with 14.04 and upgraded? Did it ship with Ubuntu out of the box? The reason I am asking is because we often see these issues on systems which aren't genuine Ubuntu, or systems that have had packages removed. The fact you're getting messages for snapd 14.04 on 16.04 is alarming.

Comment: @popey It was actually clean installed from genuine Ubuntu. The point is that I wasn't getting errors regarding **snapd** in previous days and I could easily run the simple commands like `sudo apt upgrade`. But now I don't know where have I made a mistake that I'm now having trouble with **snapd**.

Comment: I would be interested in the actual errors you get with `sudo apt -f install` or `sudo apt upgrade`.   Sorry I can't help with snap*.  If you wish to reply, please edit your question & add there, and not comments (more formatting choices exist in question/answers)

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy snapd`? Its version 2.29.4.2~14.04 is wrong, it is for trusty (14.04), not xenial (16.04).

Comment: My 16.04 machines are up to point release 16.04.4, if you are on 16.04.1 and using that kernel, something is very weird with your system.

Comment: @OrganicMarble  So what's the solution for me? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1 and the version of the snap is 2.29.4.2~14.04 which is wrong. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please give us more details, fill `## To be filed by Masroor ##` part of your question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1009944/edit). Also try to test my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try to remove snapd completely with:

```
sudo apt-get purge snapd snapd-login-service
```

Re-enable `main` repository with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
```

Then install it again:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install snapd snapd-login-service
```

This should make `/snap` directory available again.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Tried this solution with no luck .   
"snap --version  
snap    2.33.1ubuntu2  
snapd   unavailable  
series  -  "
snapd does not even appear in  
sudo service --status-all  
or anything that prompts it is indeed installed